# Writing file doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, file, save, fstream, ofstream

I'm trying to save some of my input to a file, but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know if its the file extension or whatever, but I've tried to modify it for an hour now, however it doesn't pop-up some file in my folder.

This is how my code works (not posting everything, would be too long)

This is my function:

```
void mobiltelefon::savePhoneOnFile() const
{
    ofstream out;
    out.open("C:\\temp\\phones.txt", ios::in);
    out << this->numberofphones << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < this->numberofphones; i++) {
        out << this->phones[i]->getPhonename() << endl;
        out << this->phones[i]->getPrice() << endl;
    }
    out.close();
}
```

This is how I call it in `main`:

```
case 7:
    cout << "Save the phones on file" << endl;
    fb.savePhoneOnFile();
    break;
```

I can't see my mistake. Why doesn't the file show up a file in my folder when I try to save it?

Comment: Opening a file solely for reading (`ios::in`) and writing to it don't go well together.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to open the file for writing, you should be using `ios::out` as the second argument

```
ofstream out("C:\\temp\\phones.txt", ios::out);
```

The various [open modes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) are

> `app`  seek to the end of stream before each write
>   `binary`    open in binary mode
>   `in`    open for reading
>   `out`   open for writing
>   `trunc` discard the contents of the stream when opening
>   `ate`   seek to the end of stream immediately after open

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
ofstream out;
out.open("C:\\temp\\phones.txt", ios::in);
```

You don't want to have the `std::ios::in` flag. Why would you? You're writing to a file, not reading from it.

**Explained:** `std::ofstream` bitwise-ORs the flag argument with `std::ios_base::out` in [its constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) and passes it to [`std::basic_filebuf::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open). Look up `out | in` in that link and you have the answer. The file would need to exist to be open properly. It won't be created.

Just leave out that parameter completely and it will be defaulted to `std::ios_base::out` (that's what you should have had):

```
out.open("C:\\temp\\phones.txt");
```

You might as well do it at once at construction:

```
std::ofstream out("C:\\temp\\phones.txt");
```